# Valid leaf certificate in PEM format

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I am troubleshooting an SSL certificate issue where after the.PFX conversion to.PEM file using the OpenSSL.

The certificate is from Azure App Service Managed Certificate (GoDaddy) for 1-year validity with auto-renewal.
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/05/25/App-Service-Managed-Certificate-GA.html

According to https://developer.americanexpress.com/documentation#certificate-requirements I just need to execute:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificatename.pfx -out certificatename.pem
```

Which I have done with no issue or error.

However, it is always throwing errors when uploaded to the Amex portal.

Error:

```
Please upload a valid leaf certificate in PEM format
```

Comment: Their example doesn't agree with their text, which says it wants the leaf and optionally chain cert(s) but NOT other text or keys, which that command outputs. Try `openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nokeys | sed -n '/-BEGIN/,/-END/p' >cert.pem` or if you don't have sed (e.g. obsolete Windows) use a 'plain' editor like notepad to remove all lines from that command that aren't part of blocks beginning with a `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` line and ending with an `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` line. Since it says chain is optional, you could also add `-clcerts` on the `openssl pkcs12`

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085 I am using the OpenSSL on Windows, hence there is no SED command.

Comment: And your suggestion works great with -clcerts :-), many thanks, man!